# Redirect to a single file in apache

Tags: php, apache

I have an `index.php` file in the `DocumentRoot` of a `virtualHost` in apache. It contains :

```php
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
if($path == '/')
  echo json_encode(some_data);
else if ($path == '/posts')
  echo json_encode(another_data);
```

the thing is when I send a get request to `/` it respond with the data I wanted, but when requesting `/posts` or any endpoint other than `/`, the server respond with not found page.

How can I make it use `index.php` for every request that virtualhost ?
I want all the requests to be handled by `index.php`

Comment: Look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php, `if ... elseif ... else ...`.  Syntax issue.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress deals with that by adding this to the `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Basically, you need to redirect all requests to index.php, but not using a 301 or 302, just rewriting. The `RewriteCond` lines are to make it so users can still access other files directly if they exist. You may not need those in your implementation.

Here's an explanation of the code:

- `RewriteEngine On` turns on the rewrite engine :)
- `RewriteBase /` Just makes sure we're starting from the document root
- `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` is a rule that does nothing if the request is for index.php. the [L] means no more rules will be processed.
- The two `RewriteCond` lines make sure that there's not a matching file (1st line) or directory (2nd line) for the request. If there is, then the following `RewriteRule` won't take effect, and the server will serve up that file or directory. Otherwise:
- `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]` will rewrite the request to /index.php, making your script handle the request without redirecting the user's browser to index.php.

If there is no `.htaccess` file, you'll need to add one, or add the rules to the conf file for this virtualhost. The conf file will also need to allow overrides to see the .htaccess file:

```
<Directory "/path/to/document/root">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Comment: well I am not aware of what this code does but after the .htaccess file with that content and configuring the vhost I got an error saying that there is an internal error in the server even when I'm requesting '/'

Comment: Could you post your virtualhost configuration?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the first line of the .htaccess code: `RewriteEngine On`. That could be part of the problem. I edited my answer to include it

Comment: ``
<virtualhost *:80>
    serveradmin emad@emadd.com
    documentroot "/home/emadou/Work/CineMaster/back-end"
    servername cinemmaster.com
    errorlog "/var/log/httpd/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    customlog "/var/log/httpd/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin *
    <Directory "/home/emadou/Work/CineMaster/backend">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
``

Comment: Ok, that all looks good to me. Did you try with the RewriteEngine on?

Comment: Oh, and look for your error log file. That should help point you in the right direction of what's going wrong.

Comment: I'v tried with RewriteEngine on but still throws an iternal error message, I'll take a look at the logs

Answer (score 2):

You can use [FallbackResource](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource):

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Set it in your virtual host settings or in an `.htaccess` file.